# mysql - create a summary of event data in a event list by date even with 0 events in a given time frame

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL 5.7, I am trying to create a summary of events given a list of events.

The event table looks like this:

```
mysql> select camtimestamp,camname from events where camtimestamp >= "2019-12-31" and camtimestamp < "2020-01-02" limit 10;
+---------------------+---------+
| camtimestamp        | camname |
+---------------------+---------+
| 2019-12-31 00:47:04 | wls1    |
| 2019-12-31 04:57:41 | wls1    |
| 2019-12-31 05:15:22 | wls1    |
| 2019-12-31 05:35:00 | wls1    |
| 2019-12-31 05:46:56 | wls1    |
| 2019-12-31 05:51:30 | wls1    |
| 2019-12-31 05:54:19 | wls1    |
| 2019-12-31 05:56:14 | wls1    |
| 2019-12-31 05:58:45 | wls1    |
| 2019-12-31 05:58:46 | wls1    |
+---------------------+---------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want the summary to look like this except I want the camtimestamp in the first column to increment by the hour (or what ever increments I choose) and the count to be a summary of all events between the first row and the second.

```
mysql> select camtimestamp,camname,count(camname) from events where camtimestamp >= "2019-12-31" and camtimestamp < "2020-01-02" group by camtimestamp,camname limit 10;
+---------------------+---------+----------------+
| camtimestamp        | camname | count(camname) |
+---------------------+---------+----------------+
| 2019-12-31 00:47:04 | wls1    |              1 |
| 2019-12-31 04:57:41 | wls1    |              1 |
| 2019-12-31 05:15:22 | wls1    |              1 |
| 2019-12-31 05:35:00 | wls1    |              1 |
| 2019-12-31 05:46:56 | wls1    |              1 |
| 2019-12-31 05:51:30 | wls1    |              1 |
| 2019-12-31 05:54:19 | wls1    |              1 |
| 2019-12-31 05:56:14 | wls1    |              1 |
| 2019-12-31 05:58:45 | wls1    |              1 |
| 2019-12-31 05:58:46 | wls1    |              1 |
+---------------------+---------+----------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What I am really going for is this (as a sample) result:

```
Date                  wls1  wls2
2020-01-05 12:00:00   5     7
2020-01-05 13:00:00   10    3
2020-01-05 14:00:00   2     0
2020-01-05 15:00:00   0     0
2020-01-05 16:00:00   0     2
2020-01-05 17:00:00   0     4
2020-01-05 18:00:00   1     23
2020-01-05 19:00:00   2     3
2020-01-05 20:00:00   3     4
2020-01-05 21:00:00   4     5
```

I have dabbled with creating a table that contains only timestamps from now until 2040 in hourly increments and using a join in my SELECT statement, but I can't seem to get that join between the two tables quite right.

### EDIT

The answer below gets most of the way to answering my question.  It certainly shows me that I have a ways to go to learn about mySQL and general db work.

After slightly modifying the SELECT statement it is as follows:

```
SELECT 
  startpit, 
  SUM(IF(camname='wls1', 1,0)) as wls1,
  SUM(IF(camname='wls2', 1,0)) as wls2
FROM 
(
  SELECT
    FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(camtimestamp)/@interval) * @interval
) AS startpit,
  camname,
  count(*) as num
FROM events,
(
  SELECT @interval := 3600) AS init

  GROUP BY startpit, camname
) AS baseview
GROUP BY startpit;
```

It produces this output:

```
+---------------------+------+------+
| startpit            | wls1 | wls2 |
+---------------------+------+------+
| 2019-05-01 21:00:00 |    0 |    1 |
| 2019-05-01 22:00:00 |    0 |    1 |
| 2019-05-02 06:00:00 |    0 |    1 |
| 2019-05-02 07:00:00 |    1 |    1 |
| 2019-05-02 08:00:00 |    1 |    1 |
| 2019-05-02 09:00:00 |    1 |    1 |
| 2019-05-02 10:00:00 |    1 |    1 |
| 2019-05-02 11:00:00 |    1 |    1 |
| 2019-05-02 12:00:00 |    1 |    1 |
| 2019-05-02 13:00:00 |    1 |    1 |
+---------------------+------+------+
```

I can see how to get these results and am warned about the only_full_group_by setting in MySQL 5.7.

There are still time gaps in the output where I would prefer to have zeros in both camname columns.  I can see that my PHP will have to dynamically create the SQL select statements and dynamically process the results/output.

Thank you for taking the time to answer my question!

Comment: In my last sample query result at the end, I show that between 12:00 and 13:00, there are 5 wls1 events and 7 wls2 events.  That's what I meant.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 Tricks needed:

- UNIX_TIMESTAMP() allows application of integer division to datetimes
- Pivoting isn't part of SQL proper, but `group_concat`can do something similar.

Putting it together:

```
select 
  startpit, 
  FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(startpit)+@interval) as endpit,
  group_concat(concat(camname,': ',num)) as events
from (
select
  from_unixtime(
    floor(
      unix_timestamp(camtimestamp)/@interval
    )*@interval
  ) as startpit,
  camname,
  count(*) as num
from events,
(select @interval:=3600) as init
-- where 
group by floor(unix_timestamp(camtimestamp)/@interval)*@interval, camname
) as baseview
group by startpit;
```

See [this SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/787550/5/0) (I replaced changed every second rows from 'wsl1' to 'wsl2' since your test data has only one cam.

**EDIT**

MySQL 8.0 defaults to a very buggy implementation of strict grouping. It will e.g. think, that `FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(camtimestamp)/@interval) * @interval` is (quote) "not functionally dependent" on `FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(camtimestamp)/@interval) * @interval`. This can easily be resolved by using the name of the calcualted column (`startpit`). So

```
SELECT 
  startpit, 
  FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(startpit)+@interval) AS endpit,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(camname,': ',num)) AS the_events
FROM 
(
  SELECT
    FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(camtimestamp)/@interval) * @interval
) AS startpit,
  camname,
  count(*) as num
FROM event,
(
  SELECT @interval := 3600) AS init
-- where 
  GROUP BY startpit, camname
) AS baseview
GROUP BY startpit;
```

works with MySQL 8.0, while the functionally identical original does not. This is not a flaw in the SQL, but in how MySQL 8.0 understands it. Unexperienced SQL programmers might consider this a good thing.

**EDIT 2**

There is no pivoting in SQL, i.e. **the number of columns can not depend on the data** so the format with a variable number of columns and an integer in each is not reachable via pure SQL.

Assuming, that the SQL is generated by another layer higher in the stack you can reach it by creating SQL along the lines of

```
SELECT 
  startpit, 
  FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(startpit)+@interval) AS endpit,
  SUM(IF(camname='wls1', 1,0)) as wls1,
  SUM(IF(camname='wls2', 1,0)) as wls2,
  SUM(IF(camname='wls3', 1,0)) as wls3
  -- and so on
FROM 
(
  SELECT
    FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(camtimestamp)/@interval) * @interval
) AS startpit,
  camname,
  count(*) as num
FROM event,
(
  SELECT @interval := 3600) AS init
-- where 
  GROUP BY startpit, camname
) AS baseview
GROUP BY startpit;
```

You can even put creating this SQL as a string into a stored procedure and then use `PREPARE STATEMENT` and `EXECUTE` to run it. Be advised, that tis creates a stored procedure where the number of output columns depends on the data, which is unusual at least.

Comment: OK.  I see that it is counting events between startpit and endpit.  It calculates endpit based on startpit.  How would I eliminate gaps in this approach?  For example, the sample data has a gap of a couple of hours between 00:47 and 04:57?  For the 01:00, 02:00, 03:00 startpits, I would like to have an event count of 0.  I am planning to take the output of this query to  create a graph with google's API.

Comment: Also I see other applications for the group_concat() function, but becaause I need am integer in that column for graphing purposes, the mixed data in the field won't suit my purposes.

Comment: The SQLfiddle website is cool!

Comment: @user3055756 unfortunately, this SQL is flawed. It might provide answers, but they won't always be the correct ones! If you run it against [MySQL version 8](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=91802bfe7cf9f4f210fd53dd013b75ba), it fails with the error `... this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`. `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is now the default (as it should be) for MySQL and not using it risks returning (ahem...) inconsistent results (i.e. the wrong results). What version of SQL are you running - very important for MySQL questions - it has introduced many important new features.

Comment: p.s. I would recommend that you use [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c3de777d70442b2a7b7bc58327648092) for your SQL in future - it's actively maintained, has way more servers and is the fiddle of choice here on DBA.SE!

Comment: Thanks Vérace!  Using MySQL v 5.7.

Comment: Any chance of an upgrade? In the meantime, set ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY to on/true in mysql.cnf/mysql.ini for 5.7. **DO NOT** change this no matter **how much** your colleagues and/or users ask/tell you to! Not having it set is a **RECIPE FOR DISASTER!**

Comment: @Vérace Th "flaw" is of course not in the SQL, but in the absurd way MySQL 8.0 understands it. See my first edit for an explanation.

Comment: @EugenRieck Your point about MySQL's implementation in this case being flawed is well-made - I try to avoid MySQL if at all possible - thanks for reminding me why! :-)  However, my point about avoiding (**at all costs**) leaving `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` to on/1/true (can't remember what works at the moment). Interestingly, the [docco](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) says that it is enabled by default in 5.7 which is what the OP is using - it must have been turned off! I would urge the OP to switch it back on ASAP!

Comment: @user3055756 - please see my comment above to Eugen Rieck! `SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;` to check it!

Comment: mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode; ==
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

Comment: @Vérace The implementation of strict grouping in 5.7 is much less buggy, so it **correctly** identifies my original SQL as conformant to strict grouping requirements.

Comment: @EugenRieck Your query also fails on 5.7.29 server on dbfiddle.uk - the docs say `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` became the default after 5.7.5 - so you must be running an old version of 5.7 with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` not set? I'm not denying your statement that your SQL is (or at least should be) valid - I'm **trying** to stress to the OP that **NOT**  having it set is **GENERALLY** a recipe for disaster - your possible edge case notwithstanding! IMHO, it's better for one valid query to fail (i.e. yours) than potentially having many invalid ones returning erroneous results!

Comment: Let me rephrase: The implementation of strict grouping in **the 5.7 used by the OP** is much less buggy, so it **correctly** identifies my original SQL as conformant to strict grouping requirements.